# Regex: a character should not come consecutively not more than 3 times

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In regex(python3) I have an input of 16 digit number.

I need to check the number so that no 4 consecutive digits are same

1234567890111234 ------> valid
1234**5555**67891234 ------> invalid

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for the pattern `(.)\1{3}` in the string which matches 4 consecutive same letters, if `re.search` returns None, it's a valid string:

```
import re

lst = ['12345678901112', '12345555678912']
for x in lst:
    print(x)
    print('Valid: ', re.search(r'(.)\1{3}', x) is None)

#12345678901112
#Valid:  True
#12345555678912
#Valid:  False
```

Here `(.)` matches a general single character, and capture it as group 1 which we can refer later for the following characters match with back reference `\1`, and to further make sure there are three same characters, use quantifier `{3}` on `\1`. This ensures the matched 4 characters are the same.